# Eloquent/Laravel Three-way Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm brand new to Laravel and Eloquent (and I have minimal experience with ORM in general).

Let's say I have three database tables:

1. Widgets
2. Actions
3. Users

I have modelled one junction table that has columns for:

1. `widget_id`
2. `action_id`
3. `user_id`
4. timestamp

The point of the junction is to keep a log of interactions--take a timestamp every time a `user` performs an `action` on a `widget`. I see how to model a simple many-to-many relationship using Eloquent and have this working fine, but I'm not sure how to model a more complicated three-way relationship.

For that matter, even if I had a simply many-to-many relationship (say `widget` to `action` so there would be a table called `action_widget`), how can I add an explicit model for the `action_widget` table in Eloquent, for the purpose of keeping track of extra data about each relationship (e.g. a timestamp, a comments field, etc). Or, am I just going about this in a totally wrong way?

Being new to ORM, I feel very confined as to what I can do! Does this feeling go away? :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

pivot work fine when you have 2 way relation like Categoty<->Article.
but if you have 3 way relation i think it's better to have a model called WidgetUserAction.

Edit : For these cases the new "hasManyThrough" works fine.

Comment: Thanks, using a custom model definitely seems like the best solution here.

Comment: Could you explain a little about how you would go about this? I'm facing a similar problem, but I don't know enough about Eloquent to follow it and the docs are not good enough.

Comment: hasManyThrough not works for this case. Because hasManyThrough not return relation but only value of the third attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel can create the intermediate model automatically. They're called "pivot tables".

I suggest you read [this section in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).

Comment: I've played around with this and think I like Milad's answer better for my case. Are there any other reasons to go with the pivot table method?

Comment: Not really, I haven't tried it yet. A custom model for the intermediate table sounds like a good idea.