# Laravel relationships - access the 4th table

Tags: php, laravel-5

company table:

`id | name`

user table

`id | name`

company_user pivot table:

`company_id | user_id`

Stores table:

`id | name | company_id`

user model

`public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
    }`

company model

`public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }`
`public function stores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Store::class);
    }`

now,
i want to access all the stores which belongs to all those companies where user has access to (via pivot).

`//required function`

```
public function accessibleStores()
{
   // return $this->
}
```

Is there any eloquent way to access the 4th table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent/Laravel Three-way Many-to-Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866999/eloquent-laravel-three-way-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: no, that doesnt work,

Comment: why this shouldn't work?

Comment: please read the question again

Comment: user and company relationship run through a pivot table, where store is connected to company.
here user has many companies and companies have many stores. hope you get that